# Android Activity transitions using Support v4 up to date with Android L

Tags: android, animation, android-support-library, material-design

I was implementing material design for my app. I saw that it is possible to make transitions between activities just here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2014/10/implementing-material-design-in-your.html

So i tried to follow what "Authentic motion" section says:

**ActivityMain.java**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
String transitionName = getString(R.string.transition_album_cover);
…
ActivityOptionsCompat options =
ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity,
    albumCoverImageView,   // The view which starts the transition
    transitionName    // The transitionName of the view we’re transitioning to
    );
ActivityCompat.startActivity(activity, intent, options.toBundle());
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<ImageView
    …
    android:transitionName="@string/transition_album_cover" />
```

**activity_details.xml**

```
<ImageView
    …
    android:transitionName="@string/transition_album_cover" />
```

However, this seems to make the default android activity transition, and I see no animations.

Keep in mind that I called requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS) as it says here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityOptionsCompat.html#makeSceneTransitionAnimation(android.app.Activity, android.view.View, java.lang.String)

Also all this was tested with a Nexus4 API Level 19

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation` works only on api level >= 21.
From [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html):

> Some material design features like the material theme and custom
>   activity transitions are only available on Android 5.0 (API level 21)
>   and above. However, you can design your apps to make use of these
>   features when running on devices that support material design and
>   still be compatible with devices running previous releases of Android.

Here is it's definition:

```
public static ActivityOptionsCompat makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Activity activity,
        View sharedElement, String sharedElementName) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        return new ActivityOptionsCompat.ActivityOptionsImpl21(
                ActivityOptionsCompat21.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity,
                        sharedElement, sharedElementName));
    }
    return new ActivityOptionsCompat();
}
```

> So why does that method exist in support package?

It is done so in order to maintain backward compatibility with older versions (api level <=20). From [maintaining compatibility docs](http://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html#CheckVersion):

```
// Check if we're running on Android 5.0 or higher
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    // Call some material design APIs here
} else {
    // Implement this feature without material design
}
```

Comment: So why not just add the check and create the needed variables by yourself? seems quite useless, no?

Comment: As long as the API for AppCompat stays the same then this is one less if statement that we need to continuously maintain for future releases as well. Plus it may not seem like a lot for this one, but you don't want to have to maintain tons of cases like this all over your code.

Comment: Looks like now it works backwards, I cant see docs about that

Answer (score 7):

Activity Transitions are exclusive to Android 5.0. `ActivityOptionsCompat. makeSceneTransitionAnimation` doesn't do anything if you're running 19 or below.

Comment: So why does that method exist in support package? It makes no sense... Also check this method docs. It does not say anything about api levels https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityOptionsCompat.html#makeSceneTransitionAnimation(android.app.Activity, android.view.View, java.lang.String)

Comment: It might just be there to prevent the obligation to use different code to start activities depending on the api level.

Comment: @StephaneMathis is correct. It's the same principal as `ViewCompat` (e.g. `ViewCompat.setElevation` also does nothing on API 19 and below).

Comment: same thing occurs with sceneManager... it will just not work but won´t crash where not available

Comment: Okay then, so for api level lower than L it will just be "ignored" but on L+ it will work as expected, right? Why isnt that said in the official docs?

Comment: It's a common pattern in the SDK + support lib; any class ending in `Compat` behaves this way. In some cases, a backwards-compatible behavior will be provided, whereas in others it will be a no-op.

Comment: It might be updated in the future as well. This happened to some Compat classes that first didn't do anything (no-op, so no crash) but later were filled with shims / polyfills