# IllegalArgumentException in ActivityManagerProxy

Tags: android, android-activity

**Issue**: ActivityA starts ActivityB with shared element transitions intermittently crashes
Not consistently reproducible
Api levels: 23, 24 and 25

**Code to launch activity:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
Pair<View, String> logoTransition = Pair.create(logo, getString(R.string.transition_logo));
Pair<View, String> logoTextTransition = Pair.create(logoText, getString(R.string.transition_logo_text));
ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, logoTransition, logoTextTransition);
ActivityCompat.startActivity(this, intent, options.toBundle());
```

**Stacktrace (API 23):**

```
Exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1606)
android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1555)
android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.isTopOfTask (ActivityManagerProxy.java:4787)
android.app.Activity.isTopOfTask (Activity.java:5753)
android.app.Activity.cancelInputsAndStartExitTransition (Activity.java:4075)
android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult (Activity.java:4052)
android.app.Activity.startActivity (Activity.java:4312)
android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.startActivity (ContextCompat.java)
__null__.getDrawable (ContextCompat.java)
__null__.isDeviceProtectedStorage (ContextCompat.java)
com.my.app.activity.ActivityA.startMainActivity (ActivityA.java)
```

Does anyone know what causes this behaviour?
Any proposed fix for this?

Comment: What what context is this `startActivity()` being called, i.e. what class are you in?

Comment: calling from an Activity

Comment: please refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688374/android-activity-transitions-using-support-v4-up-to-date-with-android-l) hope this will help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose, you should not use methods from support library for that versions. Sure, I can't figure out, from your existing issue due of random stacktrace.

Since Tranlsation Scene introduced form 4.4. You can include api deprecation. Moreover, it's recommended, otherwise, why we need both types?

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
       ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions
      .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, logoTransition, logoTextTransition);
       startActivity(this, intent, options.toBundle());
    } 
  else {
       ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat
      .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, logoTransition, logoTextTransition);
       ActivityCompat.startActivity(this, intent, options.toBundle());
    }
```

Comment: I thought the whole purpose of ActivityCompat is that you don't have to check SDK version to apply new functionalities. How confident are you that this would solve my problem?

Comment: @GaborPeto For ActivityCompat yes, but not for options type ActivityOptionsCompat.

Comment: @GensaGames  I still get the same exception with the same code above on Lollipop devices.
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions
                    .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MyActivity.this,                            logoImageView, "transition_name");
            startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
        }
Exception happens at startActivity().

Comment: I get the same exception, same stack trace down to Activity.startActivity, I have no AppCompat on the stack

Comment: @user3175580 Do you have additional steps to check it?

Comment: @GensaGames can you clarify? I don't know yet what causes this. I just saw this reported in Play Console crash reports for the first time (out of like 50 users, so not a good sign). The device it happend on had Android 7 and 4GB RAM. The Android source code suggests, in Parcel#writeNoException, that there were "StrictMode violations" `if (StrictMode.hasGatheredViolations()) ....`. There is a note in the comments of android.os.StrictMode: "so you should never leave StrictMode
 * enabled in applications distributed on Google Play"

Answer (score 3):

in my case this happen because i subscribe on click action two times, so startActivity was called twice in a row.

hope this can be helpful for some one :)

Answer (score 0):

Try loading transitions in the `onCreate()` method of the concerned activity like this:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);

Transition mTransition = //your transitions
getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(mTransition);
getWindow().setSharedElementExitTransition(mTransition);
```