# Activities transition with ActivityOptionsCompat issue

Tags: android, android-activity, android-transitions

I am currently developping a news application, and to enhance the app, I wanted to add transitions between my RecyclerView elements and my detail article Activity. In order to do that, I added ActivityOptionsCompat (my BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity - minSdkVersion of my app is 17) as a bundle to the startActivity method.

This is what I did :

```
List<Pair<View, String>> sharedElements = new ArrayList<>();

// I add multiple Pair to the list...

ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
            activity,
            sharedElements.toArray(new Pair[sharedElements.size()])
);

activity.startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

So, my test device was a samsung galaxy S4 (5.1) and everything was working as expected, no issue. Before the release, I tried on a samsung galaxy S8 (7.0), and this is when I found the issue. The first detail article activity works like a charm, but when I try to open a second article, I have a crash :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1697)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1646)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.isTopOfTask(ActivityManagerNative.java:6651)
at android.app.Activity.isTopOfTask(Activity.java:6185)
at android.app.Activity.cancelInputsAndStartExitTransition(Activity.java:4445)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4422)
at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:65)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4682)
at com.my.package.activities.detail.BaseDetailArticleActivity.startActivity(BaseDetailArticleActivity.java:119)
at com.my.package.activities.detail.BaseDetailArticleActivity.startActivity(BaseDetailArticleActivity.java:80)
at com.my.package.adapters.HomeAdapter$RubricHolder$1.onClick(HomeAdapter.java:335)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6261)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23748)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

I saw this post ([IllegalArgumentException in ActivityManagerProxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315167/illegalargumentexception-in-activitymanagerproxy)), but I still have the same issue. 
Did you also experiment this bug ? If so, did you manage to fix it ?

Thanks a lot,

NiCLO